# Passing list to view using Linq Union results in non-distinct results

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

Using MVC-4 and Entity Framework, I can construct a `Selectlist` from the following query that behaves as a union would be expected to do.

```
 string x = "Smith"

 var a = db.CurrentIndexes.Include(m => m.Files).Where(m => m.Name == x && m.Files.Filename.Length > 4);
 var b = db.CurrentIndexes.Include(m => m.Files).Where(m => m.PreviousName == x && m.Files.Filename.Length > 4);

var c = a.Union(b).ToList();
ViewBag.sel =  new SelectList(c, string.Empty);
```

But when I try to pass the same query to the view for iterating into a list, the results are no longer unique. I've been passing the query in a viewbag ( `ViewBag.d = c.ToList();`) I get every instance from the many side (`CurrentIndexes`).

I have tried every way I can think of to query `c` and pass that as a model or via `ViewBag`, but I get errors saying my results don't match the type of collection required by the view so I retreated to using `ViewBag` to see if I can't get the distinct results I need.

I'd be grateful for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a Distinct() clause like this:

```
var c = a.Union(b).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks but that results in red squiggles and a message saying that anonymous#1 has no such method or extension.

Comment: @JaneH Where does the anonymous type come from?

Comment: @GertArnold, the anonymous type comes from my data context, which represents a SQL Server database.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be due to the lack of the `Select(x => x.Value)` expression in the query you send to the `SelectList`. Since you can only select one value from the `SelectList` in the interface, add the expression and then return only the distinct values in the list. Something like this:

```
 var a = db.CurrentIndexes.Include(m => m.Files).Where(m => m.Name == x && m.Files.Filename.Length > 4).Select(x => x.Files.Filename);
 var b = db.CurrentIndexes.Include(m => m.Files).Where(m => m.PreviousName == x && m.Files.Filename.Length > 4).Select(x => x.Files.Filename);
 var c = a.Union(b).Distinct().ToList();
```

Other values in your query, which make the result set unique but not the value used in the `SelectList` could be the reason you aren't actually seeing only the unique values in the list. Just selecting the column you want in the list and then using the `.Distinct()` method should give you the desired results.

**EDIT**

If you wanted to pass in a value for the `Text` and `Value` parameters of a `SelectList`, then you could set up a class, e.g. if you want to pass in the PK for the record or something similar:

```
public class FileSysInfo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can select the two values you want to use for your selectlist:

```
var a = db.CurrentIndexes.Include(m => m.Files)
.Where(m => m.Name == x && m.Files.Filename.Length > 4)
.Select(x => new FileSysInfo()
{
    ID = x.Files.ID,
    Filename = x.Files.Filename
});
```

Then: `var c = a.Union(b).Distinct().List()` once you get both queries setup. Then use this in your selectlist:

```
ViewBag.sel =  new SelectList(c, "ID", "Filename");
```

Comment: Thank you, but I actually do have two columns selected for the select list, which works perfectly and returns distinct results. And I can access all the properties of list c via ViewBag or a model. They just come in multiples, rather than one of each as union usually does. And Distinct does not work on this. Please see my response to neo-ray above.